# How to calculate sum of multiple responses in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The code below outputs numeric data

```
          var meshInstances = entity.model.meshInstances;
          var mat;
          for(var i = 0; i < meshInstances.length; i++) {
     //  mat = meshInstances[i].mesh.vertexBuffer.numVertices;
          mat = parseFloat(meshInstances[i].mesh.indexBuffer[0].numIndices / 3);
console.log(mat);
```

[image]

How to output this data as a sum of all responses?
1 Line with sum

Comment: Add `mat` to a total variable, then output the variable after the loop is done.

Comment: `total += mat;`

Comment: make a sum variable and keep adding the new values to it and then print it

Comment: You could increment the value of `mat` by the `parseFloat` amount each time, rather than keep reassigning the value. Also, you could refactor the function with a `Array.reduce` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
var meshInstances = entity.model.meshInstances;
var mat, total;
for (var i = 0; i < meshInstances.length; i++) {
    //  mat = meshInstances[i].mesh.vertexBuffer.numVertices;
    mat = parseFloat(meshInstances[i].mesh.indexBuffer[0].numIndices / 3);
    total += mat;
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Anas Abdullah Al
Changed it a little and it worked, was getting 'NaN' previously

```
var meshInstances = entity.model.meshInstances;
var mat;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < meshInstances.length; i++) {
    //  mat = meshInstances[i].mesh.vertexBuffer.numVertices;
    mat = parseFloat(meshInstances[i].mesh.indexBuffer[0].numIndices / 3);
    total += mat;
}
console.log(total);
```